# How to view (sniff) http traffic?

Tags: http

I'm trying to determine how best to load/soak test a system that I'm assigned to test. I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and would like to determine how many, how often, and what kind of requests are being made from my web browser pointing to a new app the the dev team is working on in order to determine which tool would best be used to design tests for the product (JMeter for example) .

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Charles: http://www.charlesproxy.com/

It's not free, but it's inexpensive and has served be well for years now. It has the benefit of being very easy to use, albeit not as powerful as Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) is a great program for this exact purpose. It can log all incoming and outgoing HTTP traffic from your system.

Comment: Wireshark came up in discussions but I think it might provide *too much* info.

Comment: I felt the same way when I first used Wireshark too. I ended up using Fiddler to get more abridged info, but Fiddler is written in .NET it only works on a Windows system. You could try giving it a shot with Mono.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, at one point i ended up using Firebug from within Firefox. Ended up being all I needed.